# point in polygon for points on boundary of two polygon

Tags: r, terra

I have a shapefile of polygons and point that falls write on the boundary as shown below.

[image]

I did a point in polygon analysis for the point and it returns me both the polygons

```
library(terra)
terra::extract(shp, pts)

id.y lat_id lon_id  basin_id        
  1    443   1128 7120066280 
  1    443   1129 7120066280
```

How can I resolve this boundary condition to return only polygon for the point?

Answer (score 0):

Package sf has more geometric predicates (st_intersects, st_within, st_contains), which can be used in conjunction with st_join, to achieve a function similar to extract. Also in general, Sf is also more complete in its tools for vector-to-vector analysis.

However, to decide between those functions you have to answer a more fundamental question here that goes beyond computations. Do you want points that simply interact with polygons or do want points that fall strictly within a polygon?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove such duplicated points like this

```
library(terra)
e <- terra::extract(shp, pts)
i <- duplicated(e[,1])
e <- e[!i, ]
```

There are other ways to relate (see `?terra::relate`) geometries, but if a point falls on the shared boundary of two polygons, its relationship is the same with each of these polygons.